# blocking signal [hills and valleys] using python

Tags: python, signal-processing

In here i want to ask how to block the spesific signal like the signal that contains the hills and valleys using python. I have already plotted the signal like this:
[image]

How I can pick the signal in red box?

Comment: Are you just looking for any change that is relatively large in magnitude? Also do you want to filter it out (e.g. low-pass filter) or capture it or trigger another event when you receive this signal?

Comment: @BrianL, actually, I have filtered those signal using moving average filter, because I want to apply the similarity between this signal and another signal, so it is better if I just use the significant signal.

Comment: If I understand right, you want to block a signal that resembles the one in the box. Correlation could be used but it will be sensitive to phase changes. You could fourier transform the signal in a sliding window and block it based on its frequency content. Both correlation and fourier transform are in the numpy library.